# .htaccess rewrite rule to keep subdomains when redirecting to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am moving a site from an old domain with several subdomains to a new domain.  I'd like to create a rewrite rule that will just swap out the old domain for the new one, but I am not savvy enough with regular expressions & .htaccess to do this :P

I can get the 301 redirect working for the pages on the domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)oldomain.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any clues on how to modify this to include the subdomain as well?  Or am I stuck listing all the subdomains in separate rewrites?

Comment: Check this answer for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361702/redirect-from-few-urls-both-www-and-non-www-to-original-one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add a `%1`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)oldomain.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Nifty, thanks!  I was utterly baffled.  Still am, actually, but so long as it works :)

Comment: %1 references the part between the parentheses of the RewriteCond, just like $1 does for the RewriteRule.

Comment: is it possible to strip something from %1?

Comment: @Ascherer Could you be more specific please?

Comment: id like to strip the word 'dev' out of %1, figure its easy, if possible at all

Comment: @Ascherer Use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev(.*)oldomain.org [NC]` instead

Comment: Make sure to include `RewriteEngine On` before this if you don't have it or are using an `.htaccess` file.