# Redirect from few url's (both www and non-www) to original one

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

How to shorten this expression? i want instead of using 2 lines just check whatever domain is something different from mysite.com e.g. mysite.org or www.mysite.org with or without www and redirect.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.net$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also is it faster to use [OR] or do like this

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.org$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.org$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.net$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

P.S. why this works as case insensetive even when i dont use [NC]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check Apache documentation on [canonical hostnames](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#canonicalhost), your rules can be expressed as a negation

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And for the rules matching without [NC] , it probably depends on what the browser sends to the server.